# VueJs2 - How to write http service?

Tags: http, vue.js, service

I am using VueJs2. Can anyone tell me how to write http service in VueJS2 and read data incomponent.

There is sample json file in my assets folder and trying to read this json data using http. Can anyone help me here.

Comment: what do you mean "http service"? a web server or a web app?

Comment: Read api response

Comment: still no mention of http server

Comment: As for reading, did you try this https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios?

Comment: Is there only way to use axios?

Comment: I suggest you to read this [article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/here-is-the-most-popular-ways-to-make-an-http-request-in-javascript-954ce8c95aaa) that mention the most popular ways  to do what you want.

Comment: @MDM There are many ways, but VueJS docs also used it in this example https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html

Comment: @MDM I would always suggest go for the most popular library that meets your needs in case you encounter problems there'll be enough community to help, in this case axios is a good one for your escenario.

Comment: Thanks @sab. Tried this library and it's working fine.